# Origin of quantum complexity theory

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, history

Who was/were the first person/people to introduce the topic of quantum complexity theory and problem classes like BQP and QMA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class [**BQP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP#Definition) (see also [Complexity Zoo: BQP](http://complexity-zoo.net/zoo/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3aB#bqp)) was defined by

- E. Bernstein and U. Vazirani. *Quantum complexity theory*. SIAM Journal on Computing **26**, pp. 1411-1473 (1997).

The class [**QMA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QMA#Definition) (see also [Complexity Zoo: QMA](http://complexity-zoo.net/zoo/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3aQ#qma)) was defined by

- A. Kitaev. *Quantum NP*. Talk at AQIP’99: Second Workshop on Algorithms in Quantum Information Processing, DePaul University (January 1999).

which apparently built on the idea of a "quantum proof" suggested by

- E. Knill. *Quantum randomness and nondeterminism.* Technical Report LAUR-96-2186, Los Alamos National Laboratory (1996). [[arXiv:quant-ph/9610012](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9610012)].

An important relative to **QMA**, which is perhaps more delicate but which in a certain respect is a more exact analogue of **NP** for quantum computation, is the class [**QMA<sub>1</sub>** (Complexity Zoo)](http://complexity-zoo.net/zoo/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3aQ#qma1), in which the completeness constraint is perfect (*i.e.* for *YES* instances, there is a "quantum proof" with acceptance probability 1, albeit for a noiseless quantum computer). This was defined in

- S. Bravyi. *Efficient algorithm for a quantum analogue of 2-SAT* (2006).
  [[arXiv:quant-ph/0602108](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602108)]

There are other interesting quantum classes, of course. If you want an introduction to the subject, a good start would be

- John Watrous. *Quantum Computational Complexity*. Encyclopedia of Complexity and System Science, Springer (2009). [[arXiv:0804.3401](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3401)].

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't seem to find that info anywhere. I suppose Complexity Zoo would have been a good start.